# Не могу забилдить APK-шку в Unity

Tags: unity3d

*(на сайте была похожая проблема, но это не помогло)*

При билде проекта на андройд (APK файл) вылетает несколько ошибок в консоль.
Я умею читать, но похоже в понимании происходящего я никто. Перепробовал по меньшей мере 4 различных способа где пришлось ковыряться в настройках билдинга и других джунглях. И вот за что меня ругают:

"UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <4e64905d831f4883a53259ef37fb023b>:0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <4e64905d831f4883a53259ef37fb023b>:0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)"

"UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)"

"CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Советовали поиграться с настройками "Gradle" в Preferenses но это тоже не помогло.
Версия юньки вполне стабильная, VScode тоже обновлял и переустанавливал (ну мало ли?). Смена винды тоже не помогла. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!![image: еще парочку предупреждений на счет билда]

Comment: Ошибок в самом коде нет? Т.е. проект нормально переходит а режим Play?